# Concat output of 2 RestAPI calls and display results on Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sharepoint-online, rest

To overcome the 5000 view threshold of Sharepoint online, im trying to make 2 ajax calls, concat the result and display in Jquery Datatables. However the code below does not provide any output or error. Please advice.

```
var results;
var allResults = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
});

function load() {
    var call1 = $.ajax({
      url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=Created&$top=5000&$skip=0&$orderby=Date desc",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
   });
    var call2 = $.ajax({
            url: "SPO_Site/EKDL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=Created&$top=5000&$skip=5000&$orderby=Date desc",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler

   });

    function successHandler(a) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(a.body);
        results = jsonObject.d.results;
        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);
        else
            allResults = results;        
    }

    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    };

   $.when(call1, call2).done(function(a1, a2){
      console.log(allResults);
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        data:allResults ,
        columns: [{ data: "Created" }]
    });
   });  
};
```

Comment: Since you are using ```$.when```, have you tried moving the logic mentioned in ```successHandler``` into the ```$.when``` callback?

Comment: Hi Diwakar, moving the successhandler into when callback gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: successHandler is not defined

Comment: Can you check if these GET URLs are giving any data when opening in browser tab?

Comment: Yes the API calls return data. It is just the concat and datatables which is giving grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below fixed the issue.

```
var results;
var allResults = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD-MM-YYYY' ); 
    load();
});

function load() {

    var year2021 = $.ajax({    
        url: "<<List 1 API call>>",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 

    var year2020 = $.ajax({    
        url: "<<List 2 API call>>",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 

    function mySuccHandler(a) {
        results = a.d.results;
        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);
        else
            allResults = results;        
    }

    function myErrHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    };


   $.when(year2021, year2020).done(function(a1, a2){
      // console.log(allResults);
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        data:allResults,
        columns: [
                    { data: "Field 1" },
                    { data: "Field 2" }
        ]
    });
   });  
};
```